# How to merge logical vectors into a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

What I have are many columns of logical vectors, and would like to be able to merge 2 or more columns into one, and if there is any TRUE in the row to only get that a TRUE in the merged column.

Here is an example of 2 columns and the various combinations

```
X <- c(T,F,T,F,F,T,F,T,T,F,F,F)
Y <- matrix(X,nrow = 6, ncol = 2)
Y
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE 
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE
```

How to create a 3rd column "adding" the true and leaving behind if both say False, and would this also work if there were 3 or more columns to be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have logical vectors in all the columns, you can use `rowSums`

```
cbind(Y, rowSums(Y) > 0)

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

This will return `TRUE` if there is at least 1 `TRUE` in any of the row and `FALSE` otherwise. This would also work for any number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code based on Base R

```
X <- c(T,F,T,F,F,T,F,T,T,F,F,F)
Y <- as.data.frame(matrix(X,nrow = 6, ncol = 2))
unique(Y$V1)

Y$condition <- ifelse(Y$V1 == "TRUE" | Y$V2 == "TRUE","TRUE","FALSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using `apply()` and logical operator `|` that will work for any number of columns of `Y`.

```
result = cbind(Y, apply(Y, 1, FUN = function (x) Reduce(f="|", x)))
result
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```